# Reversing Latching Relay Polarity

Tags: latching-relay

I want to use the latching relay displayed schematically in the attached circuit diagram.  The designer decided to place the +V (12vDC) on the common (center) for the coil(s) and then requiring the -V on either the R(eset) or the S(et) terminals.

For reasons of circuit design that this relay is to be used in, I want to reverse the voltage polarity.  So, MY QUESTION is:

Can I connect the "V+" terminal to the - side of the power supply and use +12V as the Set and Reset trigger?  I realize that this would require flipping the diodes around and that would make the "R1" terminal the set input and the "S1" terminal the reset.  But that shouldn't matter as long as I wire the output contacts accordingly.

I'm asking whether I'm overlooking anything from an electronic/functional standpoint and also why the designer used the + power on the coil midpoint/common?  I am more used to using +volts to trigger my devices.
[image: relay schematic]

Further description from the designer is as follows:

CONTROL TERMINAL BLOCK:

V+: relay coil common terminal.

R: relay reset action signal input.

S: relay set action signal input.

SWITCH TERMINAL BLOCKS:

Rx / Cx / Sx: Switch X.

Ry / Cy / Sy: Switch Y.

When the input trigger signal R is Low(pulse or constant):

Switch X, Rx – Cx is connected and Cx – Sx is disconnected.

Switch Y, Ry – Cy is connected and Cy – Sy is disconnected.

When the input trigger signal S is Low(pulse or constant):

Switch X, Rx – Cx is disconnected and Cx – Sx is connected.

Switch Y, Rx – Cx is disconnected and Cx – Sx is connected.

Comment: You could but then you’d have to drive it with +24V. It’s meant to be ground triggered

Answer (score 3):

No, according to the datasheet, you must apply the correct polarity.

Low-side drivers are generally easier to design, so I'm not sure why you would want to drive the other way.

Answer (score 3):

In the [datasheet](https://www.tme.com/Document/d814285b03bf02fad0bab1cb322725d3/TE_RT2_bistable.pdf) the product is called a "Polarized bistable relay" which implies you cannot just swap the polarity. That's because it has a permanent magnet inside.

And so we see:

[image]

The common connection must be more positive.